# I've lost uploaded products in WordPress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have 1060 Products in my website but now only 287 of them show on the shop page & WP-Admin > Products . in Woocommerce Status Section the number of products is 1060 but ...
How can I Return my products?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what exactly are you trying to do? Have you already designed the page layouts and are the remaining products are displaying? Can you share the images if possible.

Comment: When u enter a missing product edit page can you preview the product? What errors you get? In the way you explain its unclear. Another option is to load backup